# Is there a way to determine when an abelian group $(M,+)$ admits a $R[G]$-module structure, where $R[G]$ is a group-ring.

Tags: modules, group-rings

As the title says, are there any relevant theorems, which determines when, given an abelian additive group $(M,+)$, we can determine whether $(M,+)$ admits a $R[G]$-module structure, for a unital ring $R$ and group $G$.

Are there any conditions on $R$ or $G$ that makes it easier to determine (for example $R$ *commutative* or $G$ *finite*)?

Comment: Since you can always put the trivial action $G\to\operatorname{Aut}_{\mathbb{Z}} M$, it reduces to whether $M$ can be given an $R$-module structure.  So you just need to decide whether there exists (unital) ring homomorphism $R\to\operatorname{End}_\mathbb{Z}(M)$.

Comment: Could you expand on the first part? Do you mean that g get´s sent to $f \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M,M)$?

Do you mean the action $$G \times \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M,M) \to \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M,M)?$$

Comment: So if your claim is correct, then every abelian group $M$ can be given a $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-structure, since every abelian group $M$ has a unique $\mathbb{Z}$-module structure.

Comment: You send every $g\in G$ to $\operatorname{id}_M$, in other words the $R[G]$-module structure factors through $R[G]/I\cong R$ where $I$ is the augmentation ideal generated by $\{g-1: g\in G\}$.

Comment: Yeah, but I thought a (left)-action was $G \times X \to X$ for some set $X$, so when you say $g$ to $\operatorname{id}_M$ what do you mean exactly?

Don´t know what an augmentation ideal is.

Comment: I read up on it, I see. 

From what I´ve read, it is rather that we have $\epsilon(g) = 1_R$ and $\epsilon(rg) = r$ where $\epsilon$ is a ring-homomorphism from $R[G]$ to $R$. Or do you mean that there is a correspondence between this ring-homomorphism and some group-action?

Answer (score 0):

Let $(M,+)$ be an Abelian group. Recall that the unital left $S$-module structures on $M$ are in bijective correspondence with unital ring homomorphisms $\varphi:S\to\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$.

Hence, if $(M,+)$ has a left $R[G]$-module structure then there exists a unital ring homomorphism $\psi: R[G]\to \mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$. In particular, the restriction $\varphi = \psi_{\mid_R}: R \to \mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$ is a ring homomorphism and hence yields a left $R$-module structure on $M$. Moreover, the restriction $\sigma = \psi_{\mid_G}: G \to \mathrm{Aut}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$ is a group homomorphism from $G$ to the group of $\mathbb{Z}$-automorphisms $\mathrm{Aut}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$ of $M$. And thirdly, since elements $a\in R$ and $g\in G$ commute in $R[G]$, we must have that the images $\varphi(a)$ and $\sigma(g)$ commute in $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$.

Conversely, if $M$ is a left $R$-module, say via $\varphi: R\to \mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$, and there exists a group homomorphism $\sigma: G\to \mathrm{Aut}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$ such that
$$ \varphi(a)\circ \sigma(g) = \sigma(g)\circ \varphi(a), \qquad \forall a\in R, g\in G$$
then $$\psi: R[G]\to \mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M), \qquad \sum_{g_\in G} a_g g \mapsto \sum_{g_\in G} \varphi(a_g)\circ \sigma(g)$$
is a ring homomorphism, which defines a left $R[G]$-module structure on $M$.

To summarize: you need an $R$-module structure on $M$ and a group homomorphism $G\to \mathrm{Aut}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$ that commutes with the $R$-module structure in order to define an $R[G]$-module structure on $M$.